# Possible to block SWT Canvas' default scroll on mouse wheel?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have the following:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class SSCCE {

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Display display = new Display ();
    Shell shell = new Shell (display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());      
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas (shell, SWT.NO_BACKGROUND | SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    ScrollBar hBar = canvas.getHorizontalBar ();
    ScrollBar vBar = canvas.getVerticalBar ();
    
    hBar.addSelectionListener (new SelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            System.err.println("hBar: "+vBar.getSelection());               
            canvas.redraw();                
        }
        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            widgetSelected(e);              
        }
    });
    
    vBar.addSelectionListener (new SelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            System.err.println("vBar: "+vBar.getSelection());               
            canvas.redraw();                
        }
        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            widgetSelected(e);              
        }
    });
    
    canvas.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseScrolled(MouseEvent e) {
            System.err.println("mouseScrolled: "+e.count);
        }
    });
    
    canvas.addControlListener(new ControlListener(){
        @Override
        public void controlMoved(ControlEvent e) {
            // I don't care ...
        }
        @Override
        public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
            canvas.redraw();
        }
    });
    
    canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            e.gc.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
            e.gc.fillRectangle(canvas.getBounds());         
        }
    });

    shell.setSize (500, 500);
    shell.pack();
    shell.open ();
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep ();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

}
```

... running this shows that when I scroll the mouse wheel:

1. the MouseWheelListener I added catches the event (***good***)
2. the vertical scrollbar also gets scrolled (***bad***)

... is there any way to prevent the scrolling? I tried getting all the listeners attached to the canvas & vertical scroll bar, but nothing besides what I added here was seen, so I'm guessing this is happening at the OS level (I'm on Windows Server 2022, Eclipse is 2022-09).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the lower level untyped event listener for the mouse wheel listener. With that listener you can use the `doit` flag to prevent the event being actioned:

Replace the `addMouseWheelListener` code with

```
canvas.addListener(SWT.MouseVerticalWheel, event -> {
   System.err.println("mouseScrolled: " + event.count);

   event.doit = false;
});
```

This seems to work on macOS.

Comment: Works over here as well - thanks for this. Would not have figured that one out in a million years :-)